# python consecutive elements to swap the list items

Tags: python

here my input like:

```
 ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

output:

```
 ['b','a','d','c','f','e']
```

I tried to get consecutive list but i'm getting list in between empty string so please make to remove those empty list .

```
s = list(input().split())

def swap(c, i, j):
    c[i], c[j] = c[j], c[i]
    return ' '.join(c)

result = swap(s, 0, 1)
print(list(result))
```

current output:-   `['b', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'c', ' ', 'd', ' ', 'e', ' ', 'f']`

expected output:-`['b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e','f']`

Comment: You probably don't want to turn your input list into a string? You later convert it back into a list.  You could just return c from your swap function.

Comment: next time when you ask any question mention only one expected output here are two outputs  ['b','a','d','c','f','e'] and  ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e','f'] so for you want code you can check my answer i gave solution for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple function to swap pairs that does *not change the input*:

```py
def swap_pairs(list_to_swap):
    s = list_to_swap[:] # create copy to not touch the original sequence
    for i in range(0, len(s)-1, 2):
        s[i], s[i+1] = s[i+1], s[i]
    return s

s0 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
s1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
print(swap_pairs(s0))
print(swap_pairs(s1))
# ['b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'e', 'g']
# ['b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'e']

### check if s0 and s1 are untouched:
print(s0)
print(s1)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

if you want to swap pairs 'in place', i.e. *directly change the input*, you could shorten the process to

```py
def swap_pairs(s):
    for i in range(0, len(s)-1, 2):
        s[i], s[i+1] = s[i+1], s[i]
    # return s
s1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
swap_pairs(s1)
print(s1)
# ['b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'e']
```

I think it's a matter of taste if a `return` statement should be added here. I'd consider it to be more clear *not* to return something since logically not needed. Anyway, be aware of variable scope.

Comment: @veereshG.S: glad if it helped you in any way.

Comment: Yeah Thanks its working now

Answer (score 3):

You just need to return `c` as `list`, there is not need to convert to string and back again into a list:

```
s = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

def swap(c, i, j):
  c[i], c[j] = c[j], c[i]
  return c

result = swap(s, 0, 1)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the problem.. your joining on space. change it to the following.

```
def swap(c, i, j):
  c[i], c[j] = c[j], c[i]
  return ''.join(c)
```

for your output you could also do the following.

```
l = [x for x in [your output list] if x!= ' ']
```

or

```
l = [x for x in [your output list] if len(x.strip()) > 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning only "C" and use recursion for swapping of all elements of list Then you will get expected Output. Check below code.

Output of below code: ['b','a','d','c','f','e']

```
s = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

def swap(c, i, j):
    if j<=len(c) and len(c)%2==0:
        c[i], c[j] = c[j], c[i]
        swap(c,i+2,j+2)
    elif j<len(c):
        c[i], c[j] = c[j], c[i]
        swap(c,i+2,j+2)
    return c

result = swap(s, 0, 1)
print(list(result))
```

and if you want Only output= ['b','a','c','d','e','f'] then no need of recursion just return c. Check below code:

```
s = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

def swap(c, i, j):
    c[i], c[j] = c[j], c[i]
    return c

result = swap(s, 0, 1)
print(list(result))
```

Comment: your recursion fails for uneven number of elements in the sequence. furthermore, a simple `for loop` with `range` needs less lines of code ;-)

Comment: Now you can recheck the code i just changed it now it will work for both odd or even length of list

Comment: alright, seems to be working. by the way, `if j<len(c)` makes your original solution work fine.